# How can i read extended file attribute in Java?

Tags: java

I have file with extended attribute `user.MYATTR`

when I run command: `getfattr fileName -d`, I get this:

```
user.MYATTR="attribute_value"
```

My OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

but when I am running my Java code

```
    LOG.debug("readExtentedAttribute(path={},name={}", path, name);

    UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(view.size(name));
    view.read(name, buffer);
    buffer.flip();
    String value = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buffer).toString();
    LOG.trace("extended attribute value = {}", value);
```

I am getting exception

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /opt/myfolder/myfile: Unable to get size of extended attribute 'user.MYATTR': No data available
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxUserDefinedFileAttributeView.size(LinuxUserDefinedFileAttributeView.java:141) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sk.tempest.cda.impex.service.FileServiceImpl.readExtentedAttribute(FileServiceImpl.java:39) ~[impex-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at sk.tempest.cda.impex.service.TapeMediumServiceImpl.hasDissemFlag(TapeMediumServiceImpl.java:189) ~[impex-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.hasDissemFlag(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sk.tempest.cda.impex.service.TapeStorageServiceImpl.registerNewMedia(TapeStorageServiceImpl.java:158) ~[impex-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.registerNewMedia(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sk.tempest.cda.impex.service.WorkerServiceImpl.checkNewMedia(WorkerServiceImpl.java:46) ~[impex-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found that when I want to read attribute user.MYATTR, i have to use name MYATTR.

I just wanna mention what interesting behaviour I found, that may lead to mystakes and i wanna warn you :)

My file has these two attributes:

user.MYATTR1
user.somethingElse.MYATTR2

When I was listing attributes using view.list() method I saw only this one (without user.):
MYATTR1

when i wanna read attribute value, i have to use name of attribute without 'user.', so for mentioned attributes it is:
MYATTR1
or
somethingElse.MYATTR2

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html) to the class `UserDefinedFileAttributeView`?

Reading carefully gives a few hints, why your code doesn't work properly.

For example you can check that:

> ... This *FileAttributeView* is not intended for use where the size of an
>   attribute value is larger than [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) ...

or check, if you have a security manager installed:

> ... in the case of the default provider at least, all methods that
>   access user-defined attributes require the
>   *RuntimePermission("accessUserDefinedAttributes")* permission when a
>   security manager is installed.  ...

Or try out another method to get an attribute:

> ... Where dynamic access to file attributes is required, the
>   [getAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) method may be used to read the attribute value. The attribute value is returned as a byte array (byte[]). ...

Maybe any of the hints helps you, good luck! :-)

**EDIT**

Here's an example code, which checks, if your file system provides user defined file attributes and prints them (on succes):

```
Path file = Paths.get("filename.ext");

// check that user defined attributes are supported by the file system
FileStore store = file.getFileStore();
if (!store.supportsFileAttributeView("xattr")) {
    System.err.format("UserDefinedFileAttributeView not supported on %s\n", store);
    System.exit(-1);

}
UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = file.getFileAttributeView(UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);

// list user defined attributes
if (args.length == 1) {
    System.out.println("    Size  Name");
    System.out.println("--------  --------------------------------------");
    for (String name: view.list()) {
        System.out.format("%8d  %s\n", view.size(name), name);
    }
}
```

Full source code [here](http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/cours/java/javatutorial/essential/io/examples/Xdd.java) linked from [this page](http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/cours/java/javatutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#user) your question code is from ;-)

Comment: `file.getFileStore();` isn't working for me. I used `Files.getFileStore()` as described at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#store